# Trying to combine Stoch and Awesome Oscillator

Tags: pine-script, trading

Please I'm a rookie at pine scripting and I've been trying to combine the stoch and the AO but the AO bars don't seem to appear in the indicator and there isn't any error message to indicate that there's something wrong. I was expecting the final result to look kinda like the MACD where the histogram and the smooths are interwoven together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will shift the scale of the stoch to -50 to 50 and the rescaled AO to share the same zero line. Please be aware though that it isn't the same as the standard AO zero line. You're mixing apples and oranges, different measurements with different scales, there isn't really an ideal way to do this.

```
ao = sma(hl2,5) - sma(hl2,34)

ao_sd = stdev(ao, 68)
ao_basis = sma(ao, 68)
ao_up = ao_basis + ao_sd * 3
ao_dn = ao_basis - ao_sd * 3

rescaled_ao = (ao - ao_dn) / (ao_up - ao_dn) * 100 - 50

plot(rescaled_ao, style = plot.style_histogram, color = rescaled_ao >= 0 ? color.lime : color.red)

periodK = input(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input(1, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK) - 50
d = sma(k, periodD)
plot(k, title="%K", color=#0094FF)
plot(d, title="%D", color=#FF6A00)
h0 = hline(30, "Upper Band", color=#606060)
h1 = hline(-30, "Lower Band", color=#606060)
hline(50), hline(-50)
fill(h0, h1, color=#9915FF, transp=80, title="Background")
```

Answer (score 0):

AO isn't bound to a fixed range. On different instruments it's going to show very different results, while stoch is a fixed range 0..100. I'm guessing your probably viewing a currency pair and as such the AO is very small values compared to stoch. If you switch to something like BINANCE:BTCUSDT you will see the AO now has comparatively large values and the stoch becomes flattened.

You can rescale the AO to a fixed range, but it isn't ideal. You can use methods such as the highest(AO, length) to lowest(AO, length) or do it like BB% and use the stdev of AO to set the range.

```
len = input(68)

sd = stdev(ao, len)
basis = sma(ao, len)
up = basis + sd * 2
dn = basis - sd * 2

rescaled_ao = (ao - dn) / (up - dn) * 100
plot(rescaled_ao)
```

Will rescale AO to the same range as Stoch, however now 50 is not the same as the standard AO's zeroline, but the basis (sma of AO).

Comment: First of all thanks for this answer. I noticed the AO bars did appear when i switched to BTC/USDT. I did try your code but being a rookie i don't know if i did it right cos the bars still don't show up.